# Using for loop (or apply-type functions) to make new columns with specific names found in a previously defined vector in R

Tags: r, for-loop, vector, apply

I'm trying to add columns to a dataframe where each new column is representative of a month (e.g. January, February, March, etc.) I am trying to figure out a way to create new columns in a loop where I can assign specific names to each column based on contents of a vector. This is what I have tried so far, but have been unsuccessful with.

```
my.data <- data.frame("var1" = 1:10, "var2" = 11:20)
months <- c("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", 
"August", "September", "October", "November", "December")
new.column.I.want.to.add <- rep(0, 10)

for (i in months) {
  my.data$i <- cbind(my.data, new.column.I.want.to.add)
}
```

Clearly, this does not build 12 new columns for each month filled with zeros. How do I assign the name of a column by the "ith" spot in a vector?

Comment: use `my.data[, i]` in the loop

Comment: as @RAB points out you shouldn't use the dollar sign notation here. Either  `my.data[, i] <- new.column.I.want.to.add` or `my.data[[i]] <- new.columnI.want.to.add` works.

Comment: These suggestions work great; thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually just create new columns by providing new column names and assigning a value to it:

```
my.data <- data.frame("var1" = 1:10, "var2" = 11:20)
months <- c("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", 
            "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")
my.data[, months] <- 0
```

You can then fill the columns in a for loop which will be efficient as the data.frame already has the correct size.

## Edit

As per request, if you want months over multiple years, I would construct the column names first:

```
years <- 2015:2018
monyear <- as.character(t(sapply(months, paste0, years)))
my.data[, monyear] <- 0
```

Small sidenote: `month.name` is already built into `R` and you don't need to define it.

Comment: I've thought about this route, but I need to eventually assign a year to each month over 3 years, which will result in (so far) about 36 new rows. I was hoping to automate the concatenation of the month and year strings, then assign the column name based on the new string. I could just write out "January2015", "February2015" as you suggest, but I wasn't sure that was the cleanest route to go.

Comment: See the edit. The easiest way is to construct the month+year names first. `t` is just to get a sensible order of the names.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what "t" means/does? It's hard to get meaningful information from Google when the search term is only one letter.

Comment: It means transpose and "flips" the matrix. You can access the help for a function with `?t`. As I said, in this case it was only because the order of the columns was a bit nonsensical otherwise.